# How to restrict api key google maps for iOS in an Ionic app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-maps, api-key, ionic5

I have a problem here, i can restrict calls to my google api key from my front end deployed website without any problem, but when I tried to load the map in an iphone, the origin is from ionic://localhost, the thing is that i tried to reestrict:

- ionic://localhost
- httpsionic://localhost

And no luck, the thing is that before I created an android / ios / web app in firebase, so in google console i have 3 api keys. I want to use just one api key used in my index.html as: `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?XXXXXXX&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>` and still restrict calls at least from ios/android.

1. I should include the same api key for android and ios in config.xml, eg: (for android inside the `<platform name="android"><preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="XXXXXXXXX" /></platform>`) or should i use two different api keys?
2. If I use my browser api key in de index.html and the one for android and ios (which are different) in de config.xml, i saw my billing, and google maps is ignoring the api keys in my config.xml, so i cannot separate the logic.
3. If I use one api key declared in index.html as i said, and in preference as well in config.xml, i cannot have two different type of restrictions in google console, because I cannot have HTTP reestriction for web and IOS restriction with bundle id, because if i restrict in one way, the other dissapears (anyways the bundle id restriction doesnt work). What i want to achieve is at least restrict ios/ android api keys by http, but as i said ionic://localhost doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

[API key restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table) to a specific **bundle id** or **package name** are only applicable for iOS or Android applications that uses [Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) and [Places](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro) SDKs for mobile.

Since you are implementing Google Maps with ionic you can try adding "file://" referers like this: `__file_url__`. For example, `"file:///path/to/"` should be formatted as `"__file_url__//path/to/*"`.

More information can be found at the **Note** below the restriction steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key).

If you are still having issues with your key restrictions, you can directly contact [Google Maps Platform support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) for them to be able to guide you as this issue involves your API key.

Hope this helps!